# Inverting Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

My lab assignment has this circuit.[image: Inverting Op-Amp circuit]

I couldn't find a circuit like this anywhere. So the assignment is to lower the resistance value of the R3 and to register the changes of op-amps gain. In this particular circuit it starts to visually drop reaching R3~600 Ohm. The question is - how to explain this gain drop?

Comment: What have you been able to figure out yourself so far?

Comment: Think about it like this -- when everything is working as if the op amp were ideal, what is the current across R3??

Comment: @Scott: "Current across" is nonsensical in this context.

Comment: [LM324 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm124-n.pdf) Electrical Characteristics table shows values for important non-ideal parameteres, such as `input offset voltage`  `input bias current` and `large signal voltage gain`.  Hint: for a real op-amp, the (+) and (-) inputs are *not* exactly the same voltage, because the output is not always zero.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot analyze the circuit to explain this effect assuming that the op-amp is ideal.

The DC open-loop gain of an LM324 amplifier section is typically about 1E5. It has a gain-bandwidth product of 1MHz, meaning the the open-loop gain at 1kHz will be only about 1000. The analysis you need to do **will depend on whether your input frequency is a few Hz or if it is (say) > 100Hz**.

**Let's assume it's the latter**. The ideal closed loop gain of your amplifier is -3, so you should be able to see intuitively that if the input signal is attenuated too much by R3 it will start to affect the closed-loop gain. You have a ~18:1 attenuation due to R3 = 600\$\Omega\$ so we might assume that you'd start to see a gain reduction around an op-amp gain of about 600 ~(3 * 18 * 10). That would **typically** occur at around 1.7kHz input frequency.

Do the math to get exact numbers (which will depend on the characteristics of the particular op-amp you happen to have), I'm just trying to give you a feel for what is going on.

Comment: So then R3 is shorting out the closed-loop and directly affecting the gain? Or the gain drop is only affected by the attenuation of the input signal?

Comment: R3 is reducing the voltage the op-amp inverting input itself sees for a given input voltage, so the (finite) gain of the op-amp is no longer sufficient for a high accuracy gain of -3.

Comment: So that means if we would have an ideal op-amp with infinite gain, then the gain would still remain at the same value?

Comment: @klejotajs, infinite gain at all frequencies.  Have you learned about GBW product, where the opamp gain becomes 1.  What frequency were you using... and what happens at different  frequencies?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I didn't know about gain-bandwidth product. Experiment was done with 1kHz frequency. And yes, the increase in frequency led to decrease of gain. This also explains why I didn't see the same results when I was testing the circuit with DC voltage. Then basically it means that the op-amp is unable to compensate the loss of voltage through the R3 resistor because of the gain limitation? Please correct me if I'm wrong or did not understand something appropriately.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And the higher the frequency, the less the op-amp open-loop gain is. Gain will be much (maybe 100x) higher at DC compared to 1KHz but offset voltage will be amplified and a large output offset voltage (maybe saturation) will be observed in addition to the reduced gain if you try to reduce R3 to something like 10 ohms.

Comment: @klejotajs, Yeah that is correct.  I'm sure there are other good sources, but if you want to look at this in more depth Sergio Franco's "Design with Operational Amplifiers and..." is my favorite read on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of poking at it and then wondering why something changed, analyze the circuit properly.

At first glance it appears you have a resistor divider, and a inverting amplifier.  Each has its own gain, and the overall result is the product of the two gains.  Some of the resistors change the gain of both parts.

Write the equation for each part, combine them to make the equation for the overall gain, then simplify.  Then you should be able to see how changing any one resistor will change the overall gain.  You could even generate plots of gain as a function of one of the resistor values, or whatever helps visualize what is going on.

HINT: Consider what the voltage is at the inverting input of the opamp, which is also the top of R3.

Comment: Due to virtual ground concept, I thought that voltage at the input of inverting op-amp would be zero. This is what bothers me when I try to write an equation for the gain of this circuit.

Comment: @klej: Yes, it is zero.  So now consider what that says about the current thru R3, and then how R3 affects the circuit.  Or just write the equations, reduce them, and maybe be surprised at what they simplify to.

Comment: This is the part where I couldn't wrap my head around. I assume that there is no current flowing through R3 and then the equations for the circuit are the same as without the R3 resistor.

Comment: @klej: Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you just analyze the circuit assuming ideal op-amp behavior it might get difficult to explain why the gain drops. If the op-amp behaves ideally, due to virtual ground concept, R3 would be shorted and thus would not affect the gain.

Hence my guess is that at certain value of R3, the op-amp no longer behaves ideally and node 2 will get some voltage V2 thus affecting the overall gain.

This is what I think otherwise if the op amp is assumed to be ideal then R3 should not affect the gain at all.

Answer (score 0):

The output of an op amp is not going to change instantaneously in response to changes at the input.  When the output of V1 changes, that change will essentially instantly cause the voltage at the non-inverting input to change; that will in turn cause the output voltage to change so as to oppose the change at the input.  The more the input changes (temporarily), the faster the op amp's output will change in response.

In cases where the input change is slow enough that the output can pretty well "keep up" without the differential input voltage ever getting very large, circuit gain will be dominated by the ratio of R2/R1, but if the input changes are fast enough that the op amp's behavior is no longer close to ideal, it will often be much harder to characterize the gain of the system.  Some non-ideal-op-amp models will define gain as a function of frequency, but practical op amps often have significantly non-linear characteristics whose exact behavior may be affected by factors like temperature in ways that are essentially impossible to model accurately.  Generally the best one can do is establish certain bounds on system behavior.